# Can connect to hive through beeline, but not java. Error Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri GSS initiate failed

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, kerberos

I have acces to a remote hdfs cluster with kerberos enabled. When I try to connect using beeline

```
beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://host:port/arstel;principal=principal"
```

connection is succesfull.

But when I write a java app and use the same JDBC Uri, I get

```
ERROR transport.TSaslTransport: SASL negotiation failure
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
jdbc.HiveConnection: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://host:port/arstel;principal=principal
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://host:port/arstel;principal=principal: GSS initiate failed
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: GSS initiate failed
```

My app

```
public class RecordController {
private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Class.forName(driverName);
    Connection con = DriverManager
                   .getConnection("jdbc:hive2://host:port/arstel;principal=principal");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String tableName = "evkuzmin_testHiveDriverTable";
    stmt.execute("drop table if exists " + tableName);
    stmt.execute("create table " + tableName + " (key int, value string)");
  }
}
```

Why does this happen, and how can I solve it?

I also tried this. Same result.

```
getConnection("jdbc:hive2://host:port/arstel;principal=principal;" +
                                        "auth=kerberos;" +
                                        "kerberosAuthType=fromSubject");
```

EDIT

I did not have keytab. After reading about it on stack and [here](http://www.itadmintools.com/2011/07/creating-kerberos-keytab-files.html), I created one folowing the instruction. Then I added properties to my java file this way

```
Class.forName(driverName);
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config","gss-jaas.conf");
System.setProperty("sun.security.jgss.debug","true");
System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly","false");
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf","krb5.conf");
```

After I added to `resources`

gss-jaas.conf

```
com.sun.security.jgss.initiate {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule=required
  useKeyTab=true
  useTicketCache=false
  principal="hive/host@DOMAIN"
  doNotPrompt=true
  keyTab="EvKuzmin.keytab"
  debug=true;
}
```

and krb5.conf

```
[libdefaults]
renew_lifetime = 7d
forwardable = true
default_realm = DOMAIN 
ticket_lifetime = 24h
dns_lookup_realm = false
dns_lookup_kdc = false

[realms]
DOMAIN = {
  admin_server = ms-dcs.DOMAIN 
  kdc = ms-dcs.DOMAIN 
}

[domain_realm]
.DOMAIN  = DOMAIN 
DOMAIN  = DOMAIN
```

Then the mistake changed

```
java.sql.SQLException: Could not create secure connection to jdbc:hive2://host:port/arstel;principal=hive/principal;auth=kerberos;kerberosAuthType=fromSubject: Failed to open client transport
Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Failed to open client transport [Caused by java.io.IOException: Could not instantiate SASL transport]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not instantiate SASL transport
Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Failure to initialize security context [Caused by GSSException: Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: Cannot locate default realm)]
Caused by: GSSException: Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: Cannot locate default realm)
```

ALSO

There was alrady a keytab here

```
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
```

But I have no idea what is it's realm or how to use it + I don't have access to the folder.

EDIT2 2017-08-09

Tried doing through UserGroupInformation. Got error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid attribute value for hadoop.security.authentication of Kerberos
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(UserGroupInformation.java:227)
        at com.hive.connect.controller.RecordController.main(RecordController.java:20)
```

EDIT3 2017-08-10
Using UserGroup

```
public class RecordController {
  private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
    UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
    UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("hive/principal", "EvKuzmin.keytab");
    Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager
                         .getConnection("jdbc:hive2://host:port/arstel;" +
                                          "principal=hive/principal;" +
                                          "tez.queue.name=adhoc;" +
                                          "hive.execution.engine=tez;" +
                                          "mapreduce.job.reduces=1;");
```

Error

```
java.io.IOException: Login failure for hive/principal from keytab EvKuzmin.keytab
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(UserGroupInformation.java:695)
    at com.hive.connect.controller.RecordController.main(RecordController.java:22)
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user
```

Comment: Did you create a keytab?  In what config file are you specifying it?

Comment: Use the `UserGroupInformation` class to login using keytab.

Comment: @T Updated my post.

Comment: @phi Tried userGroupInformation got a different error

Comment: I believe it is `kerberos` with a lowercase `k`

Comment: @phil What can be the reason for `Unable to obtain password from user`

Comment: `/etc/krb5.keytab` contains the master password that SSSD daemon uses to connect to a LDAP service via Kerberos -- and check your user/pwd when you connect on that Linux box. If SSSD is configured to create automatically a Kerberos ticket for you, when you connect, that would explain why you don't need to *explicitly* manage it on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I changed my krb5.conf to look like this

```
[libdefaults]
renew_lifetime = 7d
forwardable = true
default_realm = DOMAIN 
ticket_lifetime = 24h
dns_lookup_realm = false
dns_lookup_kdc = false

[realms]
DOMAIN = {
  admin_server = ms-dcs.DOMAIN 
  kdc = ms-dcs.DOMAIN 
}

[domain_realm]
.DOMAIN  = DOMAIN 
DOMAIN  = DOMAIN
```

And my java code

```
public class RecordController {
  private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    Class.forName(driverName);
    System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly","false");
    System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf","krb5.conf");

    Connection con = DriverManager
                         .getConnection("jdbc:hive2://host:port/arstel;" +
                                          "principal=hive/host@DOMAIN;" +
                                          "auth=kerberos;" +
                                          "kerberosAuthType=fromSubject");
```

EDIT

When I start it on cluster I don't need to enter password and login, but on local machine in windows I do.